# jest.mock invariant variable access: __extends

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs

I'm in the process of converting a library of react components from JS to TS and I am having an issue with jest.mock().

Before:

```
"react": "^15.6.1"
"jest": "20.0.4"
"enzyme": "^2.9.1"
```

CustomDate.js

```
...
import DatePicker from 'react-datepicker';
...
export default class CustomDate extends React.Component {
...
    render() {
        return (
            <div onChange={this.handleDivChange}>
                <DatePicker
...
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

CustomDate.test.js

```
...
import CustomDate from '../component/CustomDate';
import DatePicker from 'react-datepicker';

jest.mock('react-datepicker', () => {
    let React = require('react');
    return class DatePicker extends React.Component {
        render() {
            return (
                <div id='DatePicker'></div>
            );
        }
    };
});
...
    beforeEach(function () {
        customDate = mount(<CustomDate {...testProps}/>);
    });
...
    it('renders a DatePicker component', () => {
        console.log(customDate.find('div').at(0).html());   -> outputs <div><div id='DatePicker'></div></div>, not the react datepicker
        console.log(customDate.find('div').at(1).html());   -> outputs <div id='DatePicker'></div>, not the react datepicker
        expect(customDate.find(DatePicker).length).toBe(1);
    });
```

After:

```
"react": "^16.4.2"
"typescript": "^2.9.2"
"jest": "^23.5.0"
"ts-jest": "^23.1.4"
"enzyme": "^3.5.0"
"enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.3.0"
```

CustomDate.tsx

```
...
import DatePicker from 'react-datepicker';
...
export default class CustomDate extends Component<CustomDateProps, CustomDateState> {
...
    render() {
        return (
            <div onChange={this.handleDivChange}>
                <DatePicker
...
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

CustomDate.test.tsx

```
...
import CustomDate from '../component/CustomDate';
import DatePicker from 'react-datepicker';

jest.mock('react-datepicker', () => {
    let React = require('react');
    return class DatePicker extends React.Component {
        render() {
            return (
                <div id='DatePicker'></div>
            );
        }
    };
});
...
    beforeEach(function () {
        customDate = mount(<CustomDate {...testProps}/>);
    });
...
    it('renders a DatePicker component', () => {
        expect(customDate.find(DatePicker).length).toBe(1);
    });
```

I get the following message when I run the tests:

```
 CustomDate.test.tsx: babel-plugin-jest-hoist: The module factory of `jest.mock()` is not allowed to reference any out-of-scope variable
s.
    Invalid variable access: __extends
...
    Note: This is a precaution to guard against uninitialized mock variables. If it is ensured that the mock is required lazily, variable names prefixed with `mock` are permitted.
```

I've spent a day trying different things. Some get rid of the error, but don't really mock the DatePicker. I'm about to loose my mind.

Any help would be appreciated.

UPDATE

Compiled test file:

```
"use strict";
var __extends = (this && this.__extends) || (function () {
    var extendStatics = function (d, b) {
        extendStatics = Object.setPrototypeOf ||
            ({ __proto__: [] } instanceof Array && function (d, b) { d.__proto__ = b; }) ||
            function (d, b) { for (var p in b) if (b.hasOwnProperty(p)) d[p] = b[p]; };
        return extendStatics(d, b);
    }
    return function (d, b) {
        extendStatics(d, b);
        function __() { this.constructor = d; }
        d.prototype = b === null ? Object.create(b) : (__.prototype = b.prototype, new __());
    };
})();
exports.__esModule = true;
var React = require("react");
var mockDatePicker = /** @class */ (function (_super) {
    __extends(mockDatePicker, _super);
    function mockDatePicker() {
        return _super !== null && _super.apply(this, arguments) || this;
    }
    mockDatePicker.prototype.render = function () {
        return React.createElement("div", { id: "DatePicker1" });
    };
    return mockDatePicker;
}(React.Component));
jest.mock('react-datepicker', function () { return mockDatePicker; });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a different way to mock react-datepicker:

CustomDate.test.tsx

```
jest.mock('react-datepicker', 
    () => require.requireActual('../test/mocks/DatePickerMock').default());
```

DatePickerMock.tsx

```
import * as React from 'react';

export class DatePicker extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <div id="DatePicker"/>;
    }
}

export default DatePicker;
```

Answer (score 1):

When you're using a transpiler (e.g. TypeScript) with some code, it's often useful to be able to see the code that's actually generated to better understand why you see an error like this. For example, if I take your stubbed DatePicker class and compile it with `tsc`, I get the following:

```
"use strict";
var __extends = (this && this.__extends) || (function () {
    var extendStatics = Object.setPrototypeOf ||
        ({ __proto__: [] } instanceof Array && function (d, b) { d.__proto__ = b; }) ||
        function (d, b) { for (var p in b) if (b.hasOwnProperty(p)) d[p] = b[p]; };
    return function (d, b) {
        extendStatics(d, b);
        function __() { this.constructor = d; }
        d.prototype = b === null ? Object.create(b) : (__.prototype = b.prototype, new __());
    };
})();
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
var React = require("react");
var DatePicker = /** @class */ (function (_super) {
    __extends(DatePicker, _super);
    function DatePicker() {
        return _super !== null && _super.apply(this, arguments) || this;
    }
    DatePicker.prototype.render = function () {
        return (React.createElement("div", { id: 'DatePicker' }));
    };
    return DatePicker;
}(React.Component));
```

Here you can see that __extends is a function defined by TypeScript and placed into the "__extends" variable. This is becoming out of scope (see the error you posted) because jest moves any calls of jest.mock to the top of the file (with the help of babel).

A solution is to define your mock class outside of the closure in which you're setting up the mock. For example:

```
import * as React from "react";
class MockDatePicker extends React.Component {
   // ...
}

jest.mock("react-datepicker", () => MockDatePicker);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. class MockDatePicker extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <div id="DatePicker1"/>;
    }
};

jest.mock('react-datepicker', () => MockDatePicker);

Invalid variable access: MockDatePicker

Comment: I tried naming the mock as mockDatePicker, with lower case. The error goes away, but it's not mocking properly. TypeError: Cannot read property 'default' of undefined. On the CustomDate component when rendering the mock DatePicker.

Comment: It might be the way that the date picker is imported in your other code vs how it's now being defined. Have you tried compiling the test file with TSC to check what it's outputting?

Comment: exports['default'] = DatePicker; is how react-datepicker exports the function